# How do you get MediaWiki to render URLs in the usual way?

Tags: url, mediawiki

I've noticed that whenever a URL is long and contains unusual characters MediaWiki renders it incorrectly, for instance this URL: `http://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=C[C@H](N)CC1=CC=CC=C1` gets rendered such that the C@HCC1=CC=CC=C1 gets rendered as separate from the rest of the URL. I would like it to be rendered in its full form. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you pass the Structural Formula or the Chemical name to a [Pretty URL](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL)?  Also, have you considered the [JMOL Extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Jmol)

Comment: I hadn't considered the extension, thanks for mentioning it, but I don't know how to add it to my Wiki. Do you? I don't know how to use the pretty URL, I was left scratching my head after reading that page.

Comment: To install the extension, see [Installing Jmol extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Jmol#Installing_Jmol_extension), and for the Pretty URL, see the [Apache Guide here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache).

Comment: I haven't installed MediaWiki, I am using Wikia, which is a website that provides free Wiki capabilities. I have tried installing MediaWiki on my PC and it failed miserably, on two different operating systems too.

Comment: A 3rd Party Hosted Service will not allow installation of plugins... You need at least 3 Things: A Host with IIS or Apache(this could be your PC, 2. The MediaWiki Install Package, and the Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

[The characters that MediaWiki disallows in URLs need to be percent-encoded.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Links#Disallowed_characters)

So, for example, your link should be written as http://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=C%5BC@H%5D(N)CC1=CC=CC=C1 (`%5B` and `%5D` are the codes for `[` and `]`).